# Error using esttab in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use esttab to output regression results in R. However, every time I run it I get an error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : variable names are limited to 10000 bytes

. Any ideas how to solve it? My code is below:

```
  reg <- lm(y ~ ln_gdp + diffxln_gdp + diff + year, data=df)
  eststo(reg)
  esttab(store=reg)
```

The input data comes from approx 25,000 observations. It's all coded as numeric. I can share more information that is deemed relevant but I don't know what that would be right now.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide an example of the input data you are using others are more likely to be able to reproduce the error and help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I added some details, but not really sure what would be helpful so I'm going to wait for someone to ask for more information.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example.